# vueJS life cycle with canvas, switching components

Tags: javascript, canvas, vue.js, components, lifecycle

Im having some trouble displaying  vue components containing a canvas with different behaviors.

I want to be able to "switch component" using v-if and passing different properties.

i made a small example, see code below:

What happens now is that when i switch to 'blue' then 'red' is still "living" so when i draw the color is still 'red', although i can see the dom is changing and switching to 'canvas2'

--- COMPONENT------

```
<template>
        <div class="container-fluid">

        <canvas style="border: 1px solid black;" width="300px" height="150px" :id="'canvas'+canvasKey"></canvas>

        </div>
        </template>

    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.draw_canvas()
        },
        created: function() {
        },
        watch: {},
        props: ['canvasKey'],
        computed: {},
        methods: {
            draw_canvas: function() {
                var app = this
                var c = document.getElementById("canvas"+this.canvasKey)
                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

                if(this.canvasKey == 1) {
                    var color = 'red'
                } else if(this.canvasKey == 2) {
                    var color = 'blue'
                }

                var mousePos = function(mouseEv) {
                    let offset = $("#canvas"+app.canvasKey).offset()
                    let pos = {
                        x: mouseEv.pageX - offset.left,
                        y: mouseEv.pageY - offset.top,
                    }
                    return pos
                }

                $('#canvas'+this.canvasKey).on('mousemove' , function(ev) {
                    var pos = mousePos(ev)
                    ctx.beginPath()
                    ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
                    ctx.fillStyle = color
                    ctx.fill()
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

---CREATE COMPONENT---

```
<canvas-test v-if="color == 'red'"  canvasKey="1"></canvastest>
<canvas-test v-if="color == 'blue'" canvasKey="2"></canvas-test>
```

I hope i made my question clear, help will be much appreciated, thnks alot in advance

Comment: It's hard to tell what's happening without seeing the code that uses the component. Where is `color` defined and how? Are you creating the multiple components by hand or with a `v-for`?

Comment: @MarcoPantaleoni 
I realise its confusing, actually the color is just an example, its defined in the component itself see: 
              if(this.canvasKey == 1) {
                    var color = 'red'
                } else if(this.canvasKey == 2) {
                    var color = 'blue'
                }
im just passing '1' or '2' into the component, not using an v-for loop.

Comment: What i want to achieve in my "real project" is to be able to duplicate components with different properties, using canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a non-reactive variable inside `v-if` statements. This is not supported and the net effect is that the `v-if` evaluation doesn't changes, even if `color` does, so it's always the same component being rendered.

Switch to using a color `data` property in the parent component and, for example, use `v-model` or `v-bind:value` to use it (as described in [Using-v-model-on-Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) in the guide).
In the parent:

```
<template>
  ...
    <canvas-test v-if="color == 'red'" v-model="color"  canvasKey="1"></canvastest>
    <canvas-test v-if="color == 'blue'" v-model="color" canvasKey="2"></canvas-test>
  ...
</template>
<script>
...
export default {
  data () {
    ...
    color: 'red',
    ...
  }
  ...
  components: {
    CanvasTest
  }
  ...
}
</script>
```

in the canvas component:

```
<script>
...
export default {
  ...
  props: ['value'],  // the color is in 'value'
  ...
}
</script>
```

If you only want to have multiple components with different properties, just define their properties using [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, things are clearing up for me , i was confused (and still a bit) because of the vue docs saying: 
vm.$destroy()
Usage:

Completely destroy a vm. Clean up its connections with other existing vms, unbind all its directives, turn off all event listeners.

Triggers the beforeDestroy and destroyed hooks.

In normal use cases you shouldn’t have to call this method yourself. Prefer controlling the lifecycle of child components in a data-driven fashion using v-if and v-for.

Comment: yes, it's unusual to have to use vm.$destroy()`. But you don't necessarily need to use `v-if` and `v-for` for every component either. Just use `v-if` if you need to make its appearance depending on a condition.